# Checking session information against cookies isset confusion

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I have been trying to use some code but to use it a bit more to my purposes. The original code went as follows for the isset but it is SO confusing.

```
// Check if we're already logged in, and check session information against cookies
// credentials to protect against session hijacking
if (isset ($_COOKIE['project-name']['userID']) &&
   crypt($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
         $_COOKIE['project-name']['secondDigest']) ==
   $_COOKIE['project-name']['secondDigest'] &&
   (!isset ($_COOKIE['project-name']['username']) ||
    (isset ($_COOKIE['project-name']['username']) &&
     Users::checkCredentials($_COOKIE['project-name']['username'],
                             $_COOKIE['project-name']['digest']))))
```

My current code:

```
function encrypt($input)
{
    $hash = password_hash($input, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    return $hash;
}

function checkUserCreds($username, $password)
{
    //do code at some point
    return $username;
    return $password;
}

function checkLoggedIn($page)
{
    session_start();

    //Check if already logged in and check session information against cookies
    if (isset($_COOKIE['sukd']['id']) && encrypt($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']) == $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2'] && (!isset ($_COOKIE['sukd']['login']) || (isset ($_COOKIE['sukd']['login']) && checkUserCreds($_COOKIE['sukd']['login'], $_COOKIE['sukd']['hash']))))
     {
      //Some code here.. eventually
     }  
 }
```

Whilst I have fixed the syntax error, I am genuinely confused by the thing I am trying to copy off.

Comment: I can't understand what is your issue.. You got any errors?

Comment: I have literally just fixed the syntax error that I had but I honestly, don't get the code I am trying to copy off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function encrypt($input)
{
$hash = password_hash($input, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
return $hash;
```

}

[password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm. 

calling encrypt($input) will return hashed password

```
function checkUserCreds($username, $password)
{
//do code at some point
return $username;
return $password;
}
```

calling checkUserCreds($username, $password) will just return what you submitted
unless you have some code at 
    
//do code at some point

function checkLoggedIn($page)
{
    session_start();

```
//Check if already logged in and check session information against cookies
if (isset($_COOKIE['sukd']['id']) && encrypt($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']) == $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2'] && (!isset ($_COOKIE['sukd']['login']) || (isset ($_COOKIE['sukd']['login']) && checkUserCreds($_COOKIE['sukd']['login'], $_COOKIE['sukd']['hash'])))
 {
  //Some code here.. eventually
 }
```

}


i tried to breakdown the checkLoggedIn function

```
(1) if (isset($_COOKIE['sukd']['id']) 
(2) && encrypt($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']) == $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2'] 
(3) && (!isset ($_COOKIE['sukd']['login']) 
|| (isset ($_COOKIE['sukd']['login']) && checkUserCreds($_COOKIE['sukd']['login'], $_COOKIE['sukd']['hash'])))
 {
  //Some code here.. eventually
 } 


 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = visitors IP 
 $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = visitors browser
 $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2'] = your defined cookie( i GUESS to your password )
 $_COOKIE['sukd']['login'] = user defined cookie( i GUESS to check if login )

 (1). you check if $_COOKIE['sukd']['id'] isset and 

 (2). create a password hash by calling encrypt function and compare it to the cookie $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']
 encrypt($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']) == $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']  
 encrypt is a user defined function where you pass the combination of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2'] to retrieve password hash

 (3). you check if $_COOKIE['sukd']['login'] exist or
 cookie is set and calls the function that returns 
 $_COOKIE['sukd']['login'](username), $_COOKIE['sukd']['hash'](password)
if any of the 3 fails, it will not proceed
```

EDIT

also, you are comparing

```
$_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']
```

(if) equal to

```
encrypt($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2'])
```

that has

```
$_COOKIE['sukd']['hashv2']
```

which i believe will return false


also, be careful in number 3
it will return true if

```
$_COOKIE['sukd']['login'] is not set
```

or

```
$_COOKIE['sukd']['login'] is set and $_COOKIE['sukd']['login'], $_COOKIE['sukd']['hash'] 
will  just return the param(not empty)
```

also, make sure you set the cookies before calling checkLoggedIn()

 hope this helps

Comment: Hi, many thanks but it is the original code that I really wanted to ensure is correct and equal to what I have written in the one below. The above code is the 'original' code. Still +1 for the effort